# Persisting an Entity in derby DB Using EntityManager gives java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, sql, jpa, derby

I am getting the following Error when i try to persist an Object using Entitymanger in Derby DB:-

```
 Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL150318192139760' defined on 'TESTSEARCHS '.
    Error Code: 20000
    Call: INSERT INTO TESTSEARCHS (SEARCHID) VALUES (?)
        bind => [1 parameter bound]
    Query: InsertObjectQuery(example.com.TestSearchs@4e049f)
```

The associated code is :-

```
  public class TestA extends SuperA{
            @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
            protected TestSearchs testSearchs;
    ........
        }
```

The SuperA class provides the ID for TestA

```
  @Entity
  @XmlTransient
  @MappedSuperclass
  @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
  public class SuperA{
      @Id
      private String id;
    .........

    }
```

and the TestSearchs class is :-

```
public class TestSearchs {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @XmlTransient
    private long searchId;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected List<String> testsearch=new ArrayList<String>();

.....

}
```

I set the Id by calling setter of TestA which is Unique,And then i persit the TestA object using entityManager.Persit() but the following error occurs.Please Tell me what m i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help (on TestSearchs)?

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
```